# trying read and write on the same code in c program

Tags: c

Help I'm trying to write the data in the file. then, trying to read it back, but its not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void) {
    FILE *fptr = fopen("try.txt", "r+");
    char line[1000];
    
    fprintf(fptr, "i have new number = 1425");
        
    while (fgets(line, 1000, fptr)) {
        printf("%s",line);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: user3121023 is right. And you should definitely check fptr for not being NULL before the first usage.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a positioning function such as `rewind()` or `fseek()` between read and write operations.

Beware that the update mode for streams is very confusing and error prone, you should avoid using it and structure your programs accordingly.

Incidentally, your program will fail to open **try.txt** if it does not already exist, but you do not check for `fopen` failure so you will get undefined behavior in this case.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void) {
    char line[1000];
    FILE *fptr = fopen("try.txt", "w+");
    
    if (fptr != NULL) {
        fprintf(fptr, "I have new number = 1425\n");
        
        rewind(fptr);
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr)) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```